# Restrict MapView area on OSMdroid

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, osmdroid

I'm trying to restrict the map view for OSM given the 4 points to act as corers.

In reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403733/restricting-the-area-the-user-can-go-to-on-mapview), I am also trying to use the BoundedMapView.java (got from this [website](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/attachmentText?id=209&aid=2090027000&name=BoundedMapView.java)) to help me with this.

This is my activity codes:

```
public class POfflineMapView extends Activity implements LocationListener, MapViewConstants{

    private BoundedMapView myOpenMapView;
    //... removed unreleated variables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.offline_map_activity);
    myOpenMapView = (BoundedMapView) findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
    myOpenMapView.getTileProvider().clearTileCache();

    //removed unlreleated codes

    BoundingBoxE6 bbox = new BoundingBoxE6(north,east,south,west);
    myOpenMapView.setScrollableAreaLimit(bbox);
    }
}
```

This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <entity.BoundedMapView
        android:id="@+id/openmapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My LogCat shows this error:

```
12-28 17:24:11.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14459): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

I'm unsure why I am still getting this error; the BoundedMapView is extended from the MapView class, why is it still having an error for the Constructor?

Kindly enlighten if I do not seem to be interpreting this error correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you create a `BoundedMapView` in xml code, it calls this constructor, which is missing:

```
public BoundedMapView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, 256, new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(context), null, null, attrs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Now the app doesn't crash! However the maps and its overlays are not being displayed again, am I missing something again?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code for them.  What is that line that clears the tile cache?

Comment: It says constructor is not visible